# "The requested resource is not available" when deploying Spring MVC webapp to JBoss

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jboss

I am starting a web application with Spring MVC deploying to a JBoss 6.4 server but I get the following whenevery I try to open the main page:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /iph/

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report
JBWEB000068: message /iph/
JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.

JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1
```

This is the first time I'm using Maven and annotation-driven configuration, I have been reading very similar cases on StackOverflow but I can't figure out where the problem is.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mx.com.companyname.iph</groupId>
  <artifactId>iph</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>iph</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
      <springframework.version>4.3.13.RELEASE</springframework.version>
      <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PostgreSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.4.jre7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate ORM & Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>iph</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>iph</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is my AppConfig class:

```
package mx.com.companyname.iph.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mx.com.companyname.iph")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

This is my AppInitializer class:

```
package mx.com.companyname.iph.configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

And this is the code of my Controller class:

```
package mx.com.companyname.iph.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String main(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

My JSP view file is located on **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello world!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

The console log shows no errors. Even the first line on the following block appears to be mapping correctly the **"/"** route to the main method of my Controller:

```
17:15:18,748 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String mx.com.companyname.iph.controller.MainController.main(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
17:15:18,803 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Dec 28 17:15:17 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
17:15:18,920 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1339 ms
17:15:18,921 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/iph]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
17:15:18,921 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
17:15:18,923 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Dec 28 17:15:18 CST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
17:15:18,924 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
17:15:18,950 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 29 ms
17:15:19,006 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS015859: Implementado "iph.war" (runtime-name : "iph.war")
17:15:19,011 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Interfaz de administración http escuchando en http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
17:15:19,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Consola de administración escuchando en http://127.0.0.1:9990
17:15:19,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) inició en 5133ms - Inició 617 de 655 servicios (63 servicios son perezosos, pasivos o por demanda)
```

The main method of the Controller is not being executed. According to another similar cases and the Spring reference, I also tried to switch the Servlet Mapping route in the AppInitializer class as follows:

```
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/*"};
}
```

And Spring successfully sends the request to the main method of the Controller, however the 404 error persists and there's another error on the console:

```
17:20:23,997 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iph/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Can someone help me to find out what's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to extend your `AppConfig` class from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, after this you may have to add this overriding method in your `AppConfig` class:

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {

    configurer.enable();

}
```

Also you havn'e an implementation config of `WebApplicationInitializer` which is equivalent to `web.xml` config file:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;    
import javax.servlet.ServletException;    
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;    
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;    
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;    
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebServletConfiguration implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public void onStartup(ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {    
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();    
        webCtx.register(AppConfig.class);    
        webCtx.setServletContext(ctx);    
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = ctx.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webCtx));    
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);    
        servlet.addMapping("/");

    }

}
```

In this case you don't need the `AppInitializer` class you wrote, you can remove it. Also you need to specify the request method for that method in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path= "/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String main(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) { ...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and enable the configurer as you suggest there's no effect and 404 persists, but if I do that and change the url-pattern to `/*` I can see the index but the JSP code is not being rendered (I can see the code of the view as plain text). I'm wondering if the problem could be related to maven dependencies or server libraries on JBoss.